# How to disable ctrl + mousewheel zoom in Ionic Windows Build

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

I'm using ionic cordova to build windows. When the app is running and I click ctrl+mousewheel it zooms in and out and the text becomes larger. How can I disable this. I tried options like the below examples but it didn't work.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

or this using event

```
event.preventDefault();
```

The output, even when you press ctrl + mousewheel or ctrl + +/- it should not zoom. Thank you guyz for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to manage pointer events : style="pointer-events:none"
I hope it will help.